# How to Set parameters to formula stored in Database in MSSQl

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, formula

How to Set parameters to formula stored in table in MSSQl
Formula parameter also stored in different table

Comment: Please provide some more detail of what it is you're trying to do, preferably with an example showing table schema, data and required output. If this is related to the question you asked yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865437/calculate-different-unknown-formulas-stored-in-database-column-in-server-side-or) please update that question rather than asking again with even less information.

Comment: Please post your table schema, sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call MSSQL database formula

```
string command = "select dbo.TestFormula({0}, {1}";

string.Format(command, var1, var2);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
....
```

Hope this help